# Druids bonus ignored with only level 3 druids?

Tags: dota-underlords

When you have only 2 or 4 level 3 druids on board, is the +Level bonus completely ignored then? Or is there a special bonus (like a Extra Level 4 or some smaller stats enhancement)?

Could not find an answer and would be useful to know if you can stop leveling when the level 2 druids would be level 3 with the bonus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no secret level 4 unit. If you only have level 3 druids, you won't get any benefit from their alliance bonus.

Answer (score -1):

There is no special bonus, but if you have a Legion Commander as your lowest star unit in comparison with the druids, that Legion Commander will be guaranteed to receive a star upgrade from the Druid Alliance Bonus.